# Show that $f(x,y)=x^2+4y^2-4xy+2$ has an infinite amount of stationary points

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, coordinate-systems, stationary-point

$f(x,y)=x^2+4y^2-4xy+2$

So, $f_x=2x-4y$ and $f_y=8y-4x$

To find the stationary points we have to equal the partial derivatives to $0$:

$2x-4y=0$

$8y-4x=0$

Because we cannot find an $x$ and $y$ via the system of equations, does that mean that there are a infinite amount of $x$ and $y$ that satisfy the equation, thus proving that there indeed are infinite stationary points?

Comment: Note that $f(x,y)=(x-2y)^2$+2, so $f(x,y)$ has minimum value of $2$ and this is achieved along the entire line $x=2y$. So yeah, there's an entire line of stationary points.

Comment: @Semiclassical yeah, that seems as a good way to do it. Is my method acceptable as a proof or not, just so I can be sure. Thanks!

Comment: It's probably acceptable, depending on how you use it. I think the assertion that "we cannot find an $x$ and $y$ via the system of equations" could be explained a bit better, not just because it's an assertion provided without proof, but also because this same phrase could just as easily describe a situation where no stationary points exist.

Answer (score 1):

Under the observation by Semiclassical:
$$f(x,y)=(x-2y)^2+2,$$
you can see that that $f(x,y)\ge2$
since $(x-2y)^2\ge 0$, with $f(x,y)=2$ when $x-2y=0$.
Then $x-2y=0$ is a critical line of minima.

Comment: the gradient vanish at the indicated line and we can see how the hessian is singular but has rank one.